# TestNG mvn run tests without group

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using TestNG and Maven with surefire plugin to run tests.
I have:

```
@Test(groups={"groupA"})
TestA{}

@Test
TestB
```

I would like to have possibility to run:

```
mvn test
```

should invoke all test without any group

```
mvn test -Dgroups=groupA
```

should invoke only groupA tests ( this works by default but just added here to have it working with previous option  )

I tried to configure surefire like:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.16</version>
 <configuration>
   <excludedGroups>groupA</excludedGroups>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**mvn test** works as expected, but after
**mvn test -Dgroups=groupA**
no tests are executed

**Edit**

I found solution here:
https://labs.consol.de/blog/maven/citrus-and-testng-groups/

```
<!-- TestNG groups -->
<testGroups></testGroups>
<testGroupsExcluded>groupA</testGroupsExcluded>
<!-- /TestNG groups-->
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.16</version>
  <configuration>
    <groups>${testGroups}</groups>
    <excludedGroups>${testGroupsExcluded}</excludedGroups>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
...

<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>a-testes</id>
    <properties>
      <testGroups>a</testGroups>
      <testGroupsExcluded></testGroupsExcluded>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

But there is one problem with this solution. It works fine when we want run just always one groups of tests, for example **mvn test -P a-tests**, but when we will add another group, let's say b-tests, then after **mvn test -P a-tests, b-tests** only one group will be executed because last defined profile will overide properties... Any ideas how to combine **testGroupsExcluded**, **testGroups** properties from multiple profiles?

**Edit 2**

I just ended with solution

```
 <properties>
   <testGroups>unit</testGroups>
 </properties>
 ...
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.16</version>
   <configuration>
     <groups>${testGroups}</groups>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

But I had to assign all my tests explicitly to groups (all unassigned tests now are 'unit'), but now I can call:

**mvn test** To invoke all tests marked as unit

**mvn test -DtestGroups=groupA, groupB**  To invoke any group tests...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude, have you checked http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#beanshell ?

In surefire plugin attach testng suit config:

```
<configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
...
```

in testng.xml

```
<suite name="Emap test suite">
<test name="Emap tests">
    <method-selectors>
        <method-selector>
            <script language="beanshell"><![CDATA[        
            addClassPath("target/test-classes" );      
            return com.yourpackage.shouldExecuteTest(groups, System.getProperty("groups"));         
            ]]>
```

In static Java method shouldExecuteTest you can implement any rule you want!

Accoriding to doc, you can use those vars:

```
java.lang.reflect.Method method:  the current test method.
org.testng.ITestNGMethod testngMethod:  the description of the current test method
java.util.Map<String, String> groups:  a map of the groups the current test method belongs to.
```

System.getProperty("groups") is just -Dgroups=xxx passed from mvn invocation.

Works like a charm!